# React native NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "Connection refused"

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to deploy React Native app to my phone with an offline bundle. I haven't developed for ios before and not sure where to look for this error.
And  yes my app is named "ReactNativeTest", I didn't knew that Xcode would make a folder named "ReactNativeTestTests" haha.

So where should I begin with this problem?

```
2015-11-14 15:58:36.637 [error][tid:com.facebook.React.WebSocketExecutor][RCTWebSocketExecutor.m:127] 

WebSocket connection failed with error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "Connection refused"
2015-11-14 15:58:36.686 reactNativeTest[5240:2439923] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x136f60520 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x136f5f8b0]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x136f5ece0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x136e2fc60 'UIInputWindowController-top' V:|-(0)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x136f5f8b0]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x136f5ece0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x136f60520 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x136f5f8b0]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x136f5ece0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-11-14 15:58:38.625 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.RCTBridgeQueue][RCTWebSocketExecutor.m:70] Connection to http://localhost:8081/debugger-proxy timed out. Are you running node proxy? If                 you are running on the device, check if you have the right IP                 address in `RCTWebSocketExecutor.m`.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last row of the error gives you a hint where to look:

> Connection to http://localhost:8081/debugger-proxy timed out. Are you
>   running node proxy? If you are running on the device, check if you
>   have the right IP address in `RCTWebSocketExecutor.m`.

Additional information:

> To debug on a real device: Open the file RCTWebSocketExecutor.m and
>   change localhost to the IP address of your computer. Shake the device
>   to open the development menu with the option to start debugging.

Even better, check the documentation that Facebook provides for [Running On Device](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html).

Comment: There is an issue raised for this problem. Description can be seen and track here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1429

Answer (score 2):

I've had issues before where the IP address was wrong but most recently I hadn't been able to resolve this issue until I simply turned off WiFi and then back on again.

Same network. Same IP. Who knows why but it worked for me ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

I've get this issue "Connect Refused" once time. While I shake the phone to debug remote, the chrome open the  http://localhost:8081/debugger-proxy, but the phone and simulator can't connect to the server.It take me for days and finally I found chrome hint me cannot use cookie for this website. So I allow the chrome use cookie in this website and it work fine.